# Android Google Map api v2 night mode

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an Android application which is using full screen Google map (API 2)
The driver which is using my application would like to have the "night mode" between 10PM and 6AM for example.

Is this possible in Android ? To change the map mode to "night", similar with the Navigation Map application night mode which already exists in Android phones ?

Thanks

Comment: no it is not, the best thing you can go is dim the screen

Comment: @tyczj Since that obviously doesn't change the visual style of the map, it's not a great alternative.

Comment: @msbg my point is there is no way to do "night mode" tiles and that is really your only option to dim the screen unless you want to go and create a tile for every section of the world and every zoom level