# Night mode for Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

My question is simple. Is there a night mode for Google maps? So far I could only apply `GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL` | `GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN` | `GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE` but could not find **Night Mode**. I want something like this [image]

Please **do not suggest me to use overlay**, I already have tried. I cannot use it as I have to place markers on it.

Came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689065/android-google-map-api-v2-night-mode) post but it is 2 years old and I guess there should be some improvement.

Comment: Thank you for down vote but it would be better if you could come up with a solution.

Comment: Upvoting because I'd like to know how to do this too. It would be a nice feature to add in my current project.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Google just [announced](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/09/custom-map-styling-with-google-maps.html) having launched custom map styling for [Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases) together with a new [styling wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) that allows you to design the style once, and apply it across the board on all supported platforms: Android, iOS, JavaScript API, and even Static Maps API.

The Google Maps Android API developer docs even provide a working [night mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) style example. A [code sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StyledMapDemoActivity.java) using custom styles is also available.

Comment: yes it is working, but now even in day, night mode is showing, should I check time and enable night mode?

Answer (score 28):

Its easy just create a raw folder and right click raw folder and select new in that new select file and then type file name eg:map_in_night then click ok after it displays different formats don't confuse you just select json and click ok
and in that json file just add below code

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#242f3e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "lightness": -80
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#746855"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d59563"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d59563"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#263c3f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#6b9a76"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2b3544"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9ca5b3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#38414e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212a37"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#746855"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1f2835"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f3d19c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#38414e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212a37"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2f3948"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d59563"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#17263c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#515c6d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "lightness": -20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in onMapReady just add

```
mMap = googleMap;  
mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_night));
```

That's it

Comment: But even in day it shows Night Mode.Do I need to check the time and enable the night mode?

Comment: Yes, by using current time you can validate

Answer (score 14):

Head to :

```
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com
```

Create what you need copy the json save it in a .json file.Put it on res/raw and then use:

```
mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.name));
```

You should call the above function on : onMapReady callback.

Answer (score 0):

**Make json file R.raw.my_map_style**

```
    [
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": "40"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#ff0000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      },
      {
        "color": "#cb561a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#858585"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "color": "#858585"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "color": "#00467f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a8a8a8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "hue": "#ffc800"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#ffc800"
      },
      {
        "saturation": "25"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "42"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "8"
      },
      {
        "gamma": "0.75"
      },
      {
        "saturation": "-6"
      },
      {
        "hue": "#ffc600"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "weight": "1.77"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#aeaeae"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "color": "#8bd188"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "41"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#949595"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": -100
      },
      {
        "lightness": 45
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "hue": "#ff0000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#686868"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "weight": "1.03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#b3e9ff"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": "-35"
      },
      {
        "color": "#b6e0f3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#86c1ea"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Add in Class

```
val style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(mContext,    R.raw.my_map_style)
    googleMap?.setMapStyle(style)
```

**OutPut something like this in mobile**

[image]

Answer (score -6):

Easy solution to force night mode that i found.

- go to settings
- go to date and time
- disable automatic date and time.
- set your time to 7pm or later.

That should set the app to night mode you can change the time back when you're done traveling.